# Legal simplification of tangent equation?

Tags: calculus

I have the following equation: $h = 2d\tan \left(\dfrac{\delta}{2}\right)$. Solving it for $\delta$ results in:
$$
\delta = 2\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{h}{2d}\right) + n\pi\right),\: n \in \mathbb{Z} 
$$
Now I want to get rid of $\delta$ and replace $\delta$ in the first equation with right part of the second equation:
$$
h^{*}
=
2d^{*}\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{h}{2d}\right) + n\pi\right)\,,
\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Is it now correct to simplify this to the following equation because of the periodicity of the tangent ?
$$h^* = \dfrac{h d^*}{d}$$

Comment: You need to divide it by 2